# C++ How to getline() for an integer array using only <iostream>?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I tried using `cin.getline()`, but it only works with `char` arrays.

I want to get an input of numbers with one `char` at the end (`Q`), with spaces in between all characters/numbers, but not include the whitespace in the array itself when indexing.

Input:

> Enter integers (Q to quit): 1 2 1 8 8 9 Q

Output:

> Second smallest: 2

Comment: `getline` returns a `char*`. That's correct. Users input strings. That's a fact of life. If you want integers, you need to parse it.

Comment: I generally recommend [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) coupled with [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or plan old `>>` directly into an `int`. `>>` will fail as soon as it sees anything that isn't an `int` or whitespace, making it easy to exit the reading loop.

Answer (score 0):

`getline()` is not the right solution for this task.  Use `operator>>` instead, eg:

```
int value;
while (cin >> value)
{
    // use value as needed...
}
```

Comment: Side note: the failure condition that exits the loop will persist after the loop. You will have to `cin.clear();` the error and likely remove the Q from the stream if you intend to continue reading from the stream. You may also have to ensure that the value really is a Q and go back into the loop if it is not (nested loop).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`:

```
std::string text_line;
std::istringstream number_stream(text_line);
int number = 0;
while (number_stream >> number)
{
   std::cout << number << "\n";
}
```

This technique is often used when parsing text lines of numbers.